# Does Demat account provide the same interest rate as the savings account?

Tags: india, trading, mutual-funds

I am staying in bangalore india, I have a question
Does Demat and trading account provide the same interest rate as the savings account?

Answer (score 1):

A demat which is a shortform for 'dematerialised' account which is used to hold shares of a company in electronic form or Unit of Mutual funds.  Demat account does not pay any interest.